# how to reduce branch length in ggtree

Tags: r, plot, ggtree

I am trying to reduce branch length of the tree in `ggtree` with the following code:

```
ggtree(tree) +
   geom_tiplab() + 
   xlim(0, 0.08)
```

But it does not work. How to regulate branch length? I manage to produce this picture.[image]

Could you please help with this.

Ideally, I need a tree as in the picture attached. [image]

Comment: Great if you could include a minimal extract of data in the question using `dput(tree_or_your_data)` to make the question reproducible [MRE]

Comment: Hi, Peter. Thank you for your assistance. Shall I include it as a text file here?

Comment: Data should be pasted into the question, in the same way as you paste in code.

Comment: I have about thousand samples in the phylogenetic tree. Is there is a way to subset some part of the tree? Otherwise I can post the whole three here

Comment: Just subset the data maybe using `dput(head(your_data, n = a value which gives a minimal example))` or more usefully  subset one branch?

Comment: This command still outputs the whole data. How to subset a branch? Thank you